# Error : Cannot read property isSkipself of null - After upgraded from Angular beta to RC1

Tags: javascript, npm, angular

Here are the tsconfig :

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noLib": false
    },
```

getting error :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Removing Router from directive. solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message and it turned out I had forgotten to add `@Injectable()` on top of the service I had created.

```
@Injectable() // <-- missing
export class MyService() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am adding this @Injectable and it works fine in Chrome, but in Safari it still throws a Can't resolve all parameters for ApiService: (Http, ?).  Did you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the code that causes it. Here are discussion about similar error messages

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8519
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8820
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8704

**Update**

The error message should be improved now with https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9332